# How can I limit the height of a grid in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have in XAML:

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="83*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="3" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" RowSpacing="0" Padding="0">
            <Grid x:Name="a">
                <local:TimerView x:Name="timerView1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <local:TimerView.ProgressBar>
                        <Frame HasShadow="false" Padding="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="#AAAAAA" CornerRadius="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </local:TimerView.ProgressBar>
                    <local:TimerView.TrackBar>
                        <Frame HasShadow="false" Padding="0" Margin="0" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </local:TimerView.TrackBar>
                </local:TimerView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

I would like the height of the Grid.Row="3" to be very small, perhaps 2-3 px.  Is there a way I can limit the height to this small amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="83*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3" /> // ---> The number 3 row (don't put any *)
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
```

When you put "3" or so (without *), value is in DPI.

Note that if you don't "use" that row to display anything, you can use the margin property on the grid. I.e.:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,3"> // --> Sets a 3DPI margin at bottom
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="83*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
```

Comment: Is DPI a good way to do this so that it looks the same on different phones? I was originally thinking about pixels but not sure how to do that with phones / iPad and all the different displays that can be used. All I know is I need a small grid height there.

Comment: Yes it is! They are device-independent units recognized independently by each platform. By the way, you can get more info [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/)